# How to pass parameters to concrete implementation of IOC Dependency Resolver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interface, ninject

I have an MVC 5 web application retrieving employees' attendance records stored in a SQL Server database.  I'm also implementing dependency injection through Ninject, and the problem is that I don't know how to tell the **concrete** implementation of my attendances' class how to filter data by date. At first I was told that the site should've just shown present days' records, then I was asked to add a function to sift through the later days and now I have a problem because I don't know how to work with arguments in ninject.

First, I have the attendance class:

```
public class Comunicazione
{
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

and the class responsible for retrieving attendances from the database (constructor's arguments are Year, Month and Day, they are optional because it should show the present day's record by default)

```
public class SqlServerDbMattinale
{
    private SqlConnection _connection;
    public IList<Comunicazione> Mattinale { get; set; }

    // optional arguments added later on
    public SqlServerDbMattinale(int Anno = 0, int Mese = 0, int Giorno = 0)
    {
        _connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
        _connection.Open();

        Mattinale = new List<Comunicazione>();

        // feed with data from db and close the connection
    }
}
```

then the repository interface:

```
public interface IMattinaleRepository
{
    IList<Comunicazione> Comunicazioni { get; }
}
```

and its concrete implementation:

```
public class MattinaleRepository : IMattinaleRepository
{
    private SqlServerDbMattinale context = new SqlServerDbMattinale();

    public IList<Comunicazione> Comunicazioni
    {
        get { return context.Mattinale; }
    }
}
```

Here arise my first question: how do I pass arguments to this class? How do I let Ninject tell the framework "Hey, I need the concrete implementation of the IMattinale class with these arguments"?

First time I built the site, Ninject resolved the dependency correctly:

```
private void AddBindings()
{
    kernel.Bind<IMattinaleRepository>().To<MattinaleRepository>();
}
```

I've started tried modifying the concrete repository

```
public class MattinaleRepository : IMattinaleRepository
{
    private static int anno;
    private static int mese;
    private static int giorno;

    public MattinaleRepository(int Anno, int Mese, int Giorno)
    {
        anno = Anno;
        mese = Mese;
        giorno = Giorno;
    }

    private SqlServerDbMattinale context = new SqlServerDbMattinale(anno, mese, giorno);

    public IList<Comunicazione> Comunicazioni
    {
        get { return context.Mattinale; }
    }
}
```

but I'm given this error, and it makes sense

> Error activating int No matching bindings are available, and the type
>   is not self-bindable. Activation path:  3) Injection of dependency int
>   into parameter Anno of constructor of type MattinaleRepository  2)
>   Injection of dependency IMattinaleRepository into parameter
>   mattinaleRepository of constructor of type MattinaleController  1)
>   Request for MattinaleController

but how do I inject these parameters?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have written a factory interface,

```
public interface IMattinaleFactory
{
    MattinaleRepository Create(int Anno, int Mese, int Giorno);
}
```

its concrete counterpart,

```
public class MattinaleFactory : IMattinaleFactory
{
    private IResolutionRoot ResolutionRoot;

    public MattinaleFactory(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        ResolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    public MattinaleRepository Create(int Anno, int Mese, int Giorno)
    {
        return ResolutionRoot.Get<MattinaleRepository>(
            new ConstructorArgument("Anno", Anno),
            new ConstructorArgument("Mese", Mese),
            new ConstructorArgument("Giorno", Giorno));
    }
}
```

registered the binding,

```
kernel.Bind<IMattinaleFactory>().To<MattinaleFactory>();
```

and modified the repository class, but when I get here the parameters are all set to 0. even if the factory passes the arguments correctly.

```
public class MattinaleRepository : IMattinaleRepository
{
    private static int anno;
    private static int mese;
    private static int giorno;

    public static int Anno { get => anno; set => anno = value; }
    public static int Mese { get => mese; set => mese = value; }
    public static int Giorno { get => giorno; set => giorno = value; }

    private SqlServerDbMattinale context = new SqlServerDbMattinale(Anno, Mese, Giorno);

    public IList<Comunicazione> Comunicazioni
    {
        get { return context.Mattinale; }
    }
}
```

This is how I call the factory in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int anno = 0, int mese = 0, int giorno = 0)
{
    // this is always empty
    this.MattinaleRepository = MattinaleFactory.Create(anno, mese, giorno);

    // populate the view
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: year, month, and day should be method parameters not external dependencies.  From wikipedia for lack of a better explanation "A dependency is an object that can be used (a service). An injection is the passing of a dependency to a dependent object (a client) that would use it."   So, in your case, your dependency for the repository is SqlServerDbMattinale.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the purpose of  anno, mese, giorno ? They are stored as static values, which seems awkward combined with dependency injection